# How to find what range a number belongs in

Tags: python

Sorry the title is bad, I didn’t really know how to describe it.

So I have a range, say 122 - 983.
And I have a number x like 443.

And I can divide the range into 7ths, so that it’s

983-122 = 861

861/7 = 123

so I have

122 - 245

245 - 368

368 - 491

491 - 614

614 - 737

737 - 860

860 - 983

Now I want to figure out where my number x lies in the divided range and return the index of that range.

In this example, 443 is between 368 - 491 so it’ll return 3 since it’s within 3/7 of the range.

Now I can do this using a lot of if statements, but is there a better way?

```py
if x < 2 * (top - bottom)/7
    return 1
elif x < 3 * (top - bottom)/7:
    return 2
elif x <  4 * (top - bottom)/7:
    return 3
...
```

Comment: `443//123`----`3` indicating it's 3rd index(index starting from 1) i.e. `368 - 491`

Comment: It's guaranteed that x will be inside the range

Comment: Try this `((number - bottom - 1) * 7 // (top - bottom)) + 1`. I assumed that for 245 you want 1 not 2. Tell if I assumed wrong.

Comment: @EmilMGeorge Thank you, I knew there was a simple calculation, I just couldn't think of it for some reason. Yes, for 245, I want 1 not 2 (and other boundary numbers too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but isn't this all you need?

```
def get_range(x, lower_bound, upper_bound, n):
    return 1 + (x - lower_bound) // ((upper_bound - lower_bound) // n) \
        if upper_bound >= x >= lower_bound else 0


print(get_range(443, 122, 983, 7))
```

Output:

```
3
```

You can vary everything in there, the number you're testing `x`, the range `lower_bound` to `upper_bound` and the number of bins in your range `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use `range()`.

```
def sol(l, r, gap, num):

    if num < l or num > r:
        return 'out of range'

    step = (r-l)//gap
    rl = None
    rr = None
    for i in range(l,r+1,step):
        if i <= num:
            rl = i
        elif i > num and rl != None:
            rr = i
            break
    return (rl, rr)

l = 122
r = 983
gap = 7
num = 443
print(sol(l,r,gap,num))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min_num=122
max_num=983
bins=7
length_per_range=(983-122)/7
range_array=[122+length_per_range*x for x in range(8)]
input_number=443
for index,value in enumerate(range_array):
    if value>=input_number:
        print(index)
        break
```

Explanation: length_per_range=123, range_array= list of numbers with lower limits of the range bins you wish like [122, 245,368.....]. enumerate() helps to access elements of a list with their index values. If value (lower limit) is greater than the number, return the index of that bin. range(8) is taken so as to inlcude 983 as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop, and I think a list of tuples can be used to define your ranges.

```
ranges = [(122, 245), (245, 638), ...]
number = 500  #or whatever your number is
range_index = 0

while range_index < len(ranges):

    # If it's the first iteration and the number is below the range
    if range_index == 0 and number < ranges[range_index][0]:
        range_index = None
        break

    # If it's the last iteration and the number is above the range
    elif range_index == len(ranges) - 1 and number > ranges[range_index][1]:
        range_index = None
        break

    elif number < ranges[range_index][1]:
        break

    range_index += 1

print(range_index)  # if it's None it's because the number is not in any of the ranges
```